# How to validate only 1 array[] is required from 10 fields in CodeIgniter Form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a 1 **Add User** form that can add multiple user up to 10.

Now I need to validate only 1 field are required in `form_validation` rules. But, for sure what I need now is **not a fixed field** to validated. So, I can submit the data on the randomize field inside the form. (10 fields available, and only need 1 required field but once again **not a fixed field** because I was tried fixed field and really bothering me).

```
<form action="x" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<?php for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Username <?php echo $i; ?></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user[]">
      </div>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Validation rules inside controller's function

```
if ( ! empty($this->input->post('user', TRUE)))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[]', 'User', 'trim|alpha_numeric|min_length[2]');
}
```

I'm trying to add `required` into `user[]` validation rules, its not working because all `user[]` fields become required.

Then im trying to add `$this->form_validation->set_rules('user[0]', 'User', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[2]');` into the form validation rules, so the code is look like this.

```
if ( ! empty($this->input->post('user', TRUE)))
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[0]', 'User', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[2]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[]', 'User', 'trim|alpha_numeric|min_length[2]');
}
```

It was successfully validated for one field are required that is `Username 1` field on array `0`.
 But sometimes it really bothering me to input only 1 new user only on `Username 1`.

Because sometimes I felt really easy to input on `Username 4` or `Username 9` because the cursor is near there.

Is there any way to validate this `user[]` fields for only required on 1 field no matter which fields is there. Like `Username 3` maybe on `Username 7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple validation using **`foreach`** before creating a rules for your `form_validation`.

Just remove the required from your `form_validation` then what you need to do is validate the data is not empty, you can use 1 more helper variable to do it. for example, I'm using `$data = 0`.

```
$data = 0;
$user = $this->input->post('user', TRUE);
foreach ($user as $u) {
    if ($u != '')
    {
        $data++
    }
}

if ($data == 0) { /* then set some message to said "At least 1 data required" */ }
else 
{
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('user[]', 'User', 'trim|alpha_numeric|min_length[2]');
}

// then validate if form_validation run
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    // your code..
}
```

This will validate if `$this->input->post('user', TRUE);` input is all empty, then `$data` still be set on 0. If there is a user field submitted and not null, the `$data` will be set `++` to 1. So you can input the data wherever you wanted to maybe on `user 1` or `user 8` or any fields.

After the `$data` becomes `1` or more, you will set new validation of `form_validation` rules and then your code will run if the validation match with your requirements in the `form_validation` rules.

You can check the data are successfully submitted **if** the `form_validation` requirements are match using flashdata. If you want to check if requirements are not match, just using `else`.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'We got your submitted user : '.$data.' username');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Looking at the main execute function in the form validation library you will see that determines if the `$_POST` field is an array, and if so, runs the validation function on each item of the array separately. You can confirm this by writing your own validation function and echoing something at the top of the function. It will run one iteration per item.

With that being said you could make a rule like this in libraries/MY_Form_validation.php:

```
public function required_array($unused, $config) {
    $config = explode(',', $config);
    $items = $_POST[$config[0]];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if (!empty($item)) {
            $i++;
        }
    }
    //echo 'num items: ' . $i;
    $req = isset($config[1]) ? $config[1] : 1;
    if ($i < $req) {
        $this->set_message('required_array', 'Atleast ' . $req . ' {field} must be filled in.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

use like: `$this->form_validation->set_rules('user[]', 'User', 'required_array[user, 3]');`

However not only is this a hack, this will never be reached if there are no items in the array as CI has a special way of dealing with requires that we can't/shouldn't modify to add our function as it is a system file and that is bad practice.

Here is the section of code from validation that prevents the solution from working:

```
    if (
        ($postdata === NULL OR $postdata === '')
        && $callback === FALSE
        && $callable === FALSE
        && ! in_array($rule, array('required', 'isset', 'matches'), TRUE)
    )
    {
        continue;
    }
```

So your best bet is to check to see if one is filled in outside of CI validation.

Comment: You are welcome. If this answer helped an up vote is welcome :)